# CSS min width div not forcing it's container to be the right size as expected

Tags: cross-browser, css

I have a DIV that need a minimum width. I can't use the CSS `min-width` as its not cross-browser. I've created a inner div with a set width. When the browser is smaller than this inner div I get a scroll bar as expected.

The issue is that the outter div keeps shrinking smaller than the inner div.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jzaun/6e6yX/) for an example.

I would expect the blue to be the same width as the yellow.

Whats wrong with my CSS?

Comment: Since `outer` wraps `inner`, it will not necessarily be the same width. Try wrapping `outer` with another div, and then setting `outer` `width:100%`

Comment: @xbonez: http://jsfiddle.net/jzaun/6e6yX/5/  That doesn't seem to work. I'm not looking to make outter the same as the inner, just never any smaller than the inner div.

Comment: I meant that you'd need to specify the width for the `wrapper` rather than `inner`. Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/6e6yX/8/

Comment: @xbonez: Then is can never be any larger. I'm looking to make a cross-browser minimum width.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`min-width` is supported by all browsers except IE6. If you don't need IE6 support, you can use `min-width` like normal.

If you do need IE6 support, IE6 happens to treat `width` (and `height`) the same way that other browsers treat `min-width` (and `min-height`). You can use a hack to fake it:

```
#outer {
    width: auto !important;
    width: 1000px;
    min-width: 1000px;
}
```

IE6 will apply the second `width` property (which it will treat as `min-width`) because it incorrectly ignores the `!important` on the first one. Other browsers will set the `width` to `auto` and the `min-width` to `1000px`.

Hopefully I've understood your question correctly. Here's a modification of your original code with this update: http://jsfiddle.net/6e6yX/6/. Does this do what you're looking for?

Comment: why does ie6 ignore important?

Answer (score 1):

If you add:

```
float: left;
```

To both of them, they'll behave as you're expecting.

http://jsfiddle.net/eVWKu/