# CSS: Stop cell text from wrapping within cell

Tags: html, css

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wTtsV/7/** 

In the case of overflow in the example, the text is taken newline. How to hide the text instead of being taken newline? I already tried with `overflow: hidden`, it does not work.

Comment: Why would you think that one cell, with `width: 100%`, can be on the same line as two other cells *without* causing problems?

Comment: Why the -1? I made just a question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had success by adding `table-layout:fixed` to the table.
Then I added `overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;` to the table cell.
I had to adjust the width percentage due to the way `table-layout:fixed` renders tables.

```
#table{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

#t2{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: green;
    width:80%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[Working Example - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wTtsV/24/)

### EDIT:

Here is another method using floated elements rather than `display:table`.
A minimum width is set on the container to prevent wrapping when the window is very small.

**Caveat:**
Granted, this is not perfect as you have to specify a min-width for the container.
If text in the left and right divs can vary unpredictably, it will be difficult to determine what min-width is appropriate to prevent wrapping.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="t1">some text</div>
    <div id="t3">some other text</div>
    <div id="t2">aaaaaaaaaa...</div>
</div>
```

```
#container {
    min-width:200px;
    width:100% !important;
    width:200px;
}
#t1 {
    float:left;
    background-color: red;
}
#t2 {
    background-color: green;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#t3 {
    float:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wTtsV/26/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it does not in my case, because I do not know what can be great the content of the first cell, if there is too much text with table-layout: fixed is not handled properly.

Comment: Then you should stop with those tables. Use other solutions

Comment: Ok, how to deal with another method?

Comment: I added another method to my answer.

Comment: What do you need this for `width:100% !important;`?

Comment: That's a hack for IE6, which doesn't support `min-width`. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128181/css-min-width-div-not-forcing-its-container-to-be-the-right-size-as-expected#answer-8128423